# md-chips duplicados AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Possuo 2 elementos input com autocomplete onde através destes seleciono os itens que vem do banco e são transformados em chips.

Ambos os campos disponibilizam as mesmas informações que vem do banco para serem selecionadas, mas eu preciso fazer com que os itens que foram selecionados e transformados em chips no primeiro input não possam ser selecionados no segundo e vice e versa.

Agradeço desde já!

Abraço!

Comment: Tenta retirar o item da lista toda vez que você seleciona-lo

Comment: Podias adicionar o código relevante à pergunta?